# Finding a perpedicular segmet

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given two points $p_0 = (x_0, y_0), p_1 = (x_1, y_1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, regarding the segment connecting the two points, call it $Q$, how can we find the perpendicular segment $P$ which contains the point $p_0$ at its middle and is $2d$ units long (by euclidean distance)?

The slope of $Q$ is given by $\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$, hence the slope of $P$ is its negative inverse $\frac{x_0-x_1}{y_1-y_0}$. From here we can find the line with the slope of $P$ using the slope and the coordiates of $p_0$ though i'm not sure how to calculate the points on this line that are $d$ units away.

How can we find these points?

Comment: The problem is not clearly defined. You can have any segment along that line that is $2d$ long. Does it have to be symmetric with respect to the middle of $Q$? Or is one end on the middle (in this case you have two solutions, since the other end is at $2d$ on either side)?

Comment: To clarify: $d$ is the distance between $p_0$ and $p_1$ and you would like to find the coordinates of the points $d$ units away from $p_0$ and perpendicular to the segment $\overline{p_0p_1}$?

Comment: @Andrei Yes the point $p_0$ must be in the middle of the segment $P$. $S$ and $P$ are the same, I accidently changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

Define the $x$-displacement $X$ between $p_0$ and $p_1$:
$$
X = x_1 - x_0, 
$$
and similarly for $y$-displacement $Y$:
$$
Y = y_1 - y_0. 
$$
By the Pythagorean theorem,
$$
d^2 = X^2 + Y^2, 
$$
although we don't actually need to calculate $d$ explicitly.

Rotating the point $p_1$ counterclockwise by a right angle about the center $p_0$ yields the new point
$$
p_+ = (x_0 - Y, y_0 + X), 
$$
and after a clockwise rotation, we get the new point
$$
p_- = (x_0 + Y, y_0 - X). 
$$

You can verify that:

1. Rotation point $p_0$ is the midpoint of $p_+$ and $p_-$.
2. New points $p_+$ and $p_-$ are each $d$ units away from $p_0$.
3. New segment $\overline{p_+p_-}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{p_0p_1}$.

---

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0cguegaamy)'s an interactive visualization to see this in action. You can drag the points themselves or modify their coordinates in the left margin. Drag the parameter $s$ to rotate the segments.

Comment: $d$ is given, and is not necessarily equal to the distance from $p_0$ to $p_1$

Comment: Do you think so? I asked about this in the comments. OP doesn't explain $d$. I can modify my answer to incorporate an arbitrary value of $d$ if OP clarifies.